# How to show $\frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}$ is increasing in $x$ for $x$ sufficiently large?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I am trying to show that there exists some $\overline{x}>0$ such that $\frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}$ is increasing in $x$ for all $x > \overline{x}$.  Parameter restrictions are $0<w<1$ and $0.5 \leq L < H<1$ and $x>0$. Visual inspection in Mathematica suggests the conjecture is true.  I am having difficulty showing this through direct differentiation.

I can show that $\frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}<1$ if and only if
$\frac{w}{1-w} > \frac{(1-L)^x - (1-H)^d}{H^x-L^x}$, where $\frac{(1-L)^x - (1-H)^x}{H^x-L^x}$ is decreasing in $x$ for all $x>0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(1-L)^x - (1-H)^x}{H^x-L^x} = 0$.  I can also show that $\frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}>0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}= \infty$.

Is the above sufficient to show that there exists some $\overline{x}>0$ such that $\frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}$ is increasing in $x$ for all $x > \overline{x}$?  If not, how can I show that there exists some $\overline{x}>0$ such that $\frac{wH^x+(1−w)(1−H)^x}{wL^x+(1−w)(1−L)^x}$ is increasing in $x$ for all $x > \overline{x}$?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write the derivative of this function $f(x)$ as follows

$$f'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{(w L^x+(1-w)(1-L)^x)^2}$$

so we have to estimate the sign of $g(x)$. You can show that for the variables $H,L$ as specified

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{w^2 \log(H/L)(HL)^x}=1$$

and therefore there exists some $\bar{x}$ large enough such that for $\epsilon<1$ and $x>\bar{x}$

$$g(x)>(1-\epsilon)w^2 \log(H/L) (HL)^x>0$$

and hence we have proven that $f$ is increasing for all $x>\bar{x}$.